# WPF Binding ObservableCollection<T> T.Property to Window ViewModel in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I have inherited a class, `MyModernWindow` from `Window`, and added a property and dependency property called `MyTitleLinks`.  The type is `MyLinkCollection : ObservableCollection<MyLink>`.  In XAML, I'm trying to define the `MyTitleLinks`, and bind the `MyLink.Command` property to a property in my Window's ViewModel.

I have tried numerous ways to bind, including FindAncestor and ElementName, and I am constantly unsuccessful.

If using `{Binding AboutCommand}` or `{Binding DataContext.AboutCommand, ElementName=mainWindow}`, I get this error in the Output:

> Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target
>   element. BindingExpression:Path=AboutCommand; DataItem=null; target
>   element is 'MylLink' (HashCode=30245787); target property is 'Command'
>   (type 'ICommand')

If using `{Binding DataContext.AboutCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyModernWindow}}}`,

> Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource
>   FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType='My.Namespace.MyModernWindow',
>   AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.AboutCommand;
>   DataItem=null; target element is 'MyLink' (HashCode=35075009); target
>   property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<local:MyModernWindow x:Class="My.MainWindow"
                              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:My.Controls"
                              IsTitleVisible="True"
                              Style="{StaticResource MyModernWindow}"
                              Title="My Window"
                              WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

        <local:MyModernWindow.MyTitleLinks>
            <local:MyLink DisplayName="Support" Source="https://www.google.com/support/" />
            <local:MyLink DisplayName="About" Command="{Binding AboutCommand}" />
        </local:MyModernWindow.MyTitleLinks>
    </local:MyModernWindow>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : MyModernWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}
```

**MyLinkCollection Class**

```
public class MyLinkCollection : ObservableCollection<MyLink>
{
}
```

**MyLink Class**

```
public class MyLink : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Command), typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyLink));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(DisplayName), typeof(string), typeof(MyLink));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Source), typeof(Uri), typeof(MyLink));

        public Uri Source
        {
            get { return (Uri)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public string DisplayName
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DisplayNameProperty, value); }
        }

        public ICommand Command
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public MyLink()
        {
            SetCurrentValue(VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Visible);
        }
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public ICommand AboutCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        this.AboutCommand = new RelayCommand(OpenAboutWindow);
    }

    private void OpenAboutWindow(object o)
    {
        ModernDialog.ShowMessage("About Screen", "About", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: *"Window's DataContext is set in the ctor of the xaml.cs file"* - can you show this part? You are still missing the description of the *problem*. If you have binding errors (see Output window), then show them too please.

Comment: @Sinatr, I've updated my post to answer your questions.  Thank you.

Comment: What is `MyTitleLinks` ? Try to add links after you set `DataContext` (in code-behind) to see if that works. It should be enough to use `Command="{Binding AboutCommand}"` for any children element of window. It looks like `MyTitleLinks` is *special* (try e.g. making a button with same command inside window, it should work).

Comment: @Sinatr: `public MyLinkCollection MyTitleLinks {get;set;}` is a property of `MyModernWindow`.  You're right, it works fine with a Button, so why is this different?

Comment: I don't know what is `MyModernWindow` and what are you doing with that property. A wild guess you should do something after `Load` (where you will get properly initialized window with correct `DataContext` for bindings) and not in constructor.

Comment: @Sinatr, `MyModernWindow` inherits from `Window`.  It's the base class of my XAML Window.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/prakasht/2012/11/14/wpf-data-grid-tips/), I figured it out.  Since `MyLink` and `MyLinkCollection` aren't in the visual tree, I used a "Proxy Element" to give a context.

I gave my Window a name, created a `FrameworkElement`, then created a hidden `ContentControl`.  That's all I needed.

**Here's the working XAML:**

```
<local:MyModernWindow x:Class="My.MainWindow"
                          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                          xmlns:local="clr-namespace:My.Controls"
                          x:Name="Window"
                          IsTitleVisible="True"
                          Style="{StaticResource MyModernWindow}"
                          Title="My Window"
                          WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <local:MyModernWindow.Resources>
        <FrameworkElement x:Key="ProxyElement" DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=Window}" />
    </local:MyModernWindow.Resources>

    <ContentControl Visibility="Collapsed" Content="{StaticResource ProxyElement}"/>

    <local:MyModernWindow.MyTitleLinks>
        <local:MyLink DisplayName="Support" Source="{Binding DataContext.SupportSource, Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}}" />
        <local:MyLink DisplayName="About" Command="{Binding DataContext.AboutCommand, Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}}" />
    </local:MyModernWindow.MyTitleLinks>
</local:MyModernWindow>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the problem is that the DataContext is not inherited from the collection nor from the MyLink item.

To have WPF automatically managing the inheritance for you without the need of a proxy element you need to add "Freezable" at each step of your tree as follows:

```
public class MyLinkCollection : FreezableCollection<MyLink>
{
}
```

and

```
public class MyLink : Freezable
{
     // class body
}
```

[Xaml Behaviors Wpf](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors/AttachableCollection.cs)(a Microsoft released project) uses the same approach to propagate the DataContext inside a Xaml defined collection without the need of additional proxies